# Multiple rsync commands with one password prompt

Tags: rsync

In order to sync two source directories (e.g. ~/src1 and ~/src2) to two separate destinations (e.g. /tgt and /tgt/sub_tgt) in the remote system using a single rsync command, I am doing:

```
rsync ~/src1 uid@host:/tgt; rsync ~/src2 uid@host:/tgt/sub_tgt
```

For security reasons, the password prompt is necessary (do not want to copy the public key to the remote host) but I want to avoid the second password prompt. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not willing to go with a keyset, then you are stuck with this situation.  Each call will require authentication.

I think something like this could work though, where you initiate an ssh connection and then execute the commands after:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/reusing-ssh-session-for-repeated-rsync-commands

Comment: I see. Is it possible then to rewrite the original command (two rsyncs separated by a semicolon) in a way that I can achieve the same end? That is... the second source directory just need to go to the sub folder of the first target directory. If there is no elegant solution, your suggestion remains valuable.